# Structure from Motion Visualizer

Tags: c++, opencv, point-cloud-library, multiview

I am working on Structure from Motion. I think when it come to structure from motion, people would have came across MultiView Geometry book. It is a very good book but I found something confusing data in that book. In the below following code, there is function called Populate point cloud, which has two parameter pointcloud and pointcloud_RGB. I have point3d type values in pointcloud but I didn't find anything about pointcloud_RGB in that book and it suddenly appears in this function, which is used to fill the VEC3d rgbv. Can some one please help who came across this book.

```
void PopulatePCLPointCloud(const vector<cv::Point3d>& pointcloud, 
  const std::vector<cv::Vec3b>& pointcloud_RGB = std::vector<cv::Vec3b>() 
) 

{ 
cout<<"Creating point cloud..."; 
cloud.reset(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>); 

for (unsigned int i=0; i<pointcloud.size(); i++) { 
// get the RGB color value for the point 
        cv::Vec3b rgbv(255,255,255); 

if (i < pointcloud_RGB.size()) { 
rgbv = pointcloud_RGB[i]; 
} 

        // check for erroneous coordinates (NaN, Inf, etc.) 
                if (pointcloud[i].x != pointcloud[i].x || 
                        pointcloud[i].y != pointcloud[i].y || 
                        pointcloud[i].z != pointcloud[i].z || 
#ifndef WIN32 
                        isnan(pointcloud[i].x) || 
                        isnan(pointcloud[i].y) || 
                        isnan(pointcloud[i].z) || 
#else 
                        _isnan(pointcloud[i].x) || 
                        _isnan(pointcloud[i].y) || 
                        _isnan(pointcloud[i].z) || 
                        false 
                        ) 
                { 
                        continue; 
                } 
pcl::PointXYZRGB pclp; 
pclp.x = pointcloud[i].x; 
pclp.y = pointcloud[i].y; 
pclp.z = pointcloud[i].z; 
// RGB color, needs to be represented as an integer 
uint32_t rgb = ((uint32_t)rgbv[2] << 16 | (uint32_t)rgbv[1] << 8 | 
(uint32_t)rgbv[0]); 
pclp.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb); 
cloud->push_back(pclp); 
} 
cloud->width = (uint32_t) cloud->points.size(); // number of points 
cloud->height = 1; // a list of points, one row of data 

//Create visualizer 

pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer ("Simple Cloud Viewer"); 
viewer.showCloud (cloud); 

                 cv::waitKey(0); 
                 return; 
}
```

Comment: Literally the [first link](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/structpcl_1_1_point_x_y_z_r_g_b.html) when I searched "`pcl::PointXYZRGB`"

Comment: Thank you very much for the replay. I have pointcloud of type point3d and in that function they also used pointcloud_RGB of type vec3d, so I am asking what is there in pointcloud_RGB because they did say anything about it, so I am confused. Sorry If i didn't understand you ( I am not good in PCL).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the code snippet from MasteringOpenCV - Chapter 4. I've checked the whole project and it appears that this is some sort of a bug `pointcloud_RGB` is defined at

```
const std::vector<cv::Vec3b>& pointcloud_RGB = std::vector<cv::Vec3b>()
```

and no value is assigned except here;

```
rgbv = pointcloud_RGB[i];
```

and this is under the condition of

```
if (i < pointcloud_RGB.size())
```

the program would never go into this if since pointcloud_RGB is empty and therefore cannot be bigger than i. That's why it should run without any problems.

The real point cloud is `pcl::PointXYZRGB pclp;` and it is filled in here with XYZ coordinates + RGB values;

```
pcl::PointXYZRGB pclp; 
pclp.x = pointcloud[i].x; 
pclp.y = pointcloud[i].y; 
pclp.z = pointcloud[i].z; 
// RGB color, needs to be represented as an integer 
uint32_t rgb = ((uint32_t)rgbv[2] << 16 | (uint32_t)rgbv[1] << 8 | 
(uint32_t)rgbv[0]);
```

Of course there's always the possibility of sending an e-mail to the author and ask for a clarification.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment.  I am getting 7.0e008 re-projection error of 3d point cloud, do you think it is very huge ?

Comment: It seems quite big. You can examine your point cloud; you're supposed to obtain a 3D model of your object of interest after all.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replay, My visualized pointcloud is weird.  Can you send your email ? I would like to discuss more with you.